# Equal chords on two circles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I am stuck on this geometry construction:

From a point $O$ draw a line that "cuts" two equal chords on two non-equal circles.
Construction must be made with compass and ruler.

Comment: Are the circles given or do you have to find them?

Comment: For many configurations there will not be such a line.  It seems to make more sense to be given two circles and ask to find a line that cuts equal chords without the point $O$ being involved.

Comment: Yes, the two circles are given, I am sorry I can't post a drawing here. Let's say we have a smaller circle with radius r at the left and a bigger one with radius R at the right. Let the point be somewhere between the two of them.

Comment: Still, even with these conditions, the existence of such a line depends on at least the ratio between the two radii. For example, if $r << R$ and $O$ lies on the line joining their centers, no such line will exist.

Comment: I agree, but let's deal with the general configuration and not the exceptions.

Comment: Maybe exceptional is the configuration of your problem.

Comment: Start with the tangents to one circle - if they cut the other circle, than you may seek a solution as desired and in some cases there are to solutions.